# Sending Multipart MimeMessage sends an empty email

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, mime-message, tomee-7

I am working on this project that requires us to send daily reports via mail in pdf and xlsx format. I read about using Multipart messages for such a task, so I've written a code below in order to complete it:

```
public void sendEmail(String toEmail, String subject, String body, ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBaos, ByteArrayOutputStream xlsBaos) {
    System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // SMTP Host
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // TLS Port
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // enable authentication
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // enable STARTTLS
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            // override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
    try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            // set message headers
            msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
            msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config
                    .getProperty("reporter.mail.username"), "DailyReport"));

            msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(
                    Config.getProperty("reporter.mail.username"), false));

            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));

            msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // Create a multipart message for attachment
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Create the message body part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);
            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Second part is attachment
            MimeBodyPart pdfAttachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource pdfAttachment = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdfBaos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
            String pdfFileName = "report.pdf";
            pdfAttachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(pdfAttachment));
            pdfAttachmentBodyPart.setFileName(pdfFileName);

            MimeBodyPart xlsAttachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource xlsAttachment = new ByteArrayDataSource(xlsBaos.toByteArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            String xlsFileName = "report.xls";
            xlsAttachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(xlsAttachment));
            xlsAttachmentBodyPart.setFileName(xlsFileName);

            multipart.addBodyPart(pdfAttachmentBodyPart);
            multipart.addBodyPart(xlsAttachmentBodyPart);

            // Send the complete message parts
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            // msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");


            System.out.println("Message is ready");
            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this sends only an empty email to the desired address. Now I suspected something was wrong with the way I am sending files, so I tried just sending the text bodyPart, but delivered mail was also empty. I also tried creating MimeMultipart with the "mixed" parameter, but that didn't fix anything.

Setting text to MimeMessage through setText method works fine, but that leaves me with the problem of how to send .pdf and .xlsx attachments along with it.

I am using javax.mail 1.5.0-b01 and apache TomEE 7.0. Reports are generated through jasperreports.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code mostly looks fine, but you might want to make it better by fixing any of these [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  And if possible, you might want to [upgrade to the latest version of JavaMail, currently 1.6.1](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).  Then, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problem with the code.

1. Ensure that you have the appropriate versions of 
   mail.jar
   activation.jar
2. Another thing if you can you try is this:

   `String pdfFileName = "report.pdf";
   DataSource source = new FileDataSource(pdfFilename);
   // DataSource pdfAttachment = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdfBaos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");`